# Is there a 3d game engine without a built-in physics engine?

Tags: opengl, 3d

I know about jMonkeyEngine, Ardor3D, etc. Yes, I've also heard of LWJGL and OpenGL (the both are essentially the same, though) but neither of them really suit me. I don't want to deal too much in the backend stuff, because though it's really cool, I find it tedious. I have a good understanding of what goes on behind the scenes, but I need a higher-level API *without* a built-in physics engine. Is there such an engine? It would *definitely* be a plus if the engine has cool shader effects like specular lighting, normal mapping, etc.

EDIT: The engine has to be Java-based.

Comment: Why do you need engine *without* physics? If you dont need physics or want to use own physics, what keeps you from simply ignoring the physics provided by engine? For example if object does not have collider in Unity, it is like it does not exist for their physics engine.

Comment: Hm...are we restricted to the built-in physics engine in jMonkeyEngine or is it possible for us to write our own physics?

Comment: Just use Unity and create ur own physics engine if u want to deal with the topic, or if u want to make a game without physics, then just don't apply a physics component to ur entities. Then there is no physics calculations. Very Easy x)

Comment: @wondra Consider making your answer-like comment an actual answer.

Comment: @LarsViklund it is not really an answer: 1) OP did not answer directly why he needs it so I could post full answer 2) judging from from reaction this question is jMonkey specific and sadly I don't know the engine. If you do know the answer OP is interested in, feel free to take the credit.

Comment: Jmonkey  (my engine of choice) contains a physics engine but you certainly don't need to use it, I wrote my own and JMonkey was perfectly happy with that (in fact I'd half forgotten it had one). Same with all the rest, I use JMonkey as a nice scene graph based openGL binding but most of the rest is mine